# Participle phrase as adjunct or modifier

Tags: phrases, modifiers, adjuncts

Consider the below sentence:

> Revolution broke out in France in 1789, most cogently symbolised then as now by the storming of the Bastille on 14 July.

The participle phrase *most cogently symbolised then as now by the storming of the Bastille on 14 July* - is it an adjunct (modifying the clause itself) or is it a modifier (modifying the noun 'revolution')?

Comment: Either interpretation is possible, although if that phrase modifies "revolution" then it might seem as though it describes revolutions in general, and I'm not sure that the writer means that. (Also, "cogently" doesn't quite seem to fit in this context, at least IMO.)

Comment: It is an adjunct, but not a modifying one. It's a supplementary adjunct that has "revolution" as its anchor.

Comment: @BillJ. May I ask what the primary difference between a supplement and an adjunct is?

Comment: Adjuncts may be modifiers or supplements. Modifying adjuncts are tightly integrated into the structure of the clause, while supplements, by contrast, are loosely attached expressions set of by intonation (and usually punctuation) presenting supplementary non-integrated content. Compare: "The kids were _happily_ playing outside" (modifier) ~ "_Happily_, the kids were playing outside" (supplement). Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. There is one more thing I would like to ask you, though, if that is all right with you: what is the difference in meaning between your two example sentences? Are they not interpreted in the same way? Thank you again; your explanations of grammar are among the most helpful on this StackExchange.

Comment: @BillJ I have read about free adjuncts formed from present participles; I guess it's equally valid if one were formed from past participles?

Comment: @Cheng Yes, but past-participial supplements are quite rare. Two examples come to mind: "[**Born** in Aberdeen], he had never been further than Edinburgh." / "[**Based** on the latest sales data], we need to increase our prices"

Comment: @BillJ Could you possibly be coaxed into bundling up your comments above into an answer below?:) I enjoyed [your related ELU answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/483145/2085). I'm not always clear on [how to choose the anchor for supplements](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar/EB0ABC6005935012E5270C8470B2B740/adjuncts-modifiers-and-supplements/E56EF25F189AD293220FC3C337238FF3). Here I could see myself alternatively choosing the whole clause *Revolution broke out in France in 1789* as the anchor, not merely *Revolution* alone

Answer (score 1):

> *Revolution broke out in France in 1789,* [*most cogently symbolised then*
> *as now by the storming of the Bastille on 14 July*].

I'd take the bracketed clause as a supplementary adjunct. Supplements are not modifiers, but loosely attached expressions set off by intonation (and usually punctuation) presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Supplements have a semantic anchor that they refer to. In your example, the anchor could be simply "revolution", or perhaps more saliently the whole of the clause "revolution broke out in France in 1789".